# Comparing the dipole moment of water and ethanol

Tags: dipole

Why is the dipole moment of water (1.85D) larger than ethanol (1.66D)?

I thought the inductive effect from ethyl would develop more delta - charge on oxygen.. hence increasing the charge and the dipole moment

Answer (score 4):

It's probably due to the slight difference in [electronegativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity) between H (2.2) and C (2.55)

Here's some data on gas-phase dipole moments from the CRC Handbook:

- Water - 1.85 D
- Methanol - 1.7 D
- Ethanol - 1.66 D
- n-Propanol - 1.55 D
- n-Butanol - 1.66 D

Using some [incorrect data](http://macro.lsu.edu/howto/solvents/Dipole%20Moment.htm), I pointed to a possible odd-even effect. Using the correct gas-phase dipole moments, we see that these are all pretty similar (i.e., +/- ~0.2D).

Certainly water has the highest dipole moment, but H is slightly more electropositive than C, suggesting that as a likely cause.

Comment: Side note - my initial thought was to the odd-even effect, so when I quickly found online data suggesting a large dipole moment for methanol and n-propanol, it seemed reasonable. Always better to go to quality sources.